# Does Docker alpine image support openjdk19

Tags: java, dockerfile

Does Docker alpine image support openjdk19. If yes how do we install openjdk19 using Docker alpine image 3.16.2. I am able to install openjdk11 but not openjdk19.

Comment: You should not install JDK to a container image, but use a JDK container image instead - like eclipse-temurin:19-jdk-alpine

Answer (score 0):

You've got this a little backwards.

You're looking for someone that produces a supported image of OpenJDK 19 with an Alpine Linux image.

The [Eclipse Temurin project](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin) supports official builds of OpenJDK in Docker, and it also comes with an Alpine image.

**Be very careful**, given that it is up to this maintainer to decide what base images they choose to use, and they *might* drop support for Alpine.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your responses. I have been asked not to use Eclipse Temurin project and stick to alpine 3.16.2 base image. I am able to install openjdk17 with this image.I am going ahead with that.

Comment: @Narasimha, whomever told you that is setting you up for failure. You'll have to install OpenJDK in the container every time there's an update, which - given that it's using a different C library (musl) - is a lot of extra work. I give this advice as a developer going through an upgrade cycle myself, and I would not want the overhead of installing this runtime on top of developing stuff.

Comment: @Narasimha: To make matters harder, you'll be on the hook to update the installations in the image when there's a critical CVE against Java. Whomever is giving you the direction to just install Java in the image is not considering the complexity of it.

Comment: Hi Makoto, thanks for the detailed explanation. Do you have a code snippet to show how exactly we can install openjdk19 using the eclipse temurin project ? I can do a little poc and suggest to my team.

Comment: @Narasimha: `FROM eclipse-temurin:19-alpine` ? That's all you need to base your image.

Comment: I will suggest this to our team and hopefully we can implement in our project. Thank you for your continued suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late to the game, but developing on aamd64 / mac and deploying to x86 my working setup looks like this:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:21-jdk

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /var/app
COPY target/my_packaged_jar.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dserver.port=8080", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

And to deploy using cross building:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --push -t *mycr*.azurecr.io/*myserver*  -f Dockerfile .
```

This works for Java19 as well and has shows decent performance.
They also have a tiny server alternative that might be even more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

use this image openjdk:19-alpine

https://hub.docker.com/layers/openjdk/library/openjdk/19-alpine/images/sha256-5bf18c827959c2d7b56b27328547faeefba886f23be35c0fe2093a5353135d99?context=explore

Comment: That image is both deprecated and not suitable for production use.

Comment: @Makoto, do you know reasons of deprecation?

Comment: @AlexElin:  [Because they said so](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/505)